# Fixing off-center radio text

Tags: javascript, css, radio-button

[image]

I'm trying to make a survey webapp on heroku (javascript mostly) and the off-center text on these radio buttons is rather annoying. What's an easy way to center it and slide it off to the side a little? Formatting is all done with CSS right now. Currently how I'm formatting these radio inputs is as so....

```
.radio-input{
    background: #D4E7ED;
    padding:20px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `vertical-align: middle` on *label* and *radio button* with `padding-top: 1%` on *label* for aligning text and radio button:

```
label {
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top: 1%;
}
.rdo{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AuqkE/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example I created using a similar approach that Coder outlined. It includes the background coloring you specified and it wraps the radio button and text in divs. It seemed to behave pretty well for me:

the css:

```
.radio-input {
    padding-top:20px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.radio-input-text {
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.background {
    background: #D4E7ED;
    width:300px;
}
```

the HTML:

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="radio-input">
        <input type="radio" value="Great" id="Great" /><span class="radio-input-text">Great</span>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-input">
        <input type="radio" value="Okay" id="Okay" /><span class="radio-input">Okay</span>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-input">
        <input type="radio" value="Very Bad" id="VeryBad" /><span class="radio-input">Very Bad</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ewilansky/nknL2/1/)